# Fill in missing dates in Google Sheet query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a Google Sheet query like this:

`=QUERY(A2:I;"select I, sum(C) * -1, count(C) group by I order by I ASC"; 1)`

And it yields a result like this:

[image]

In the source data not all months are occurring. But in the aggregation I want to see all the months. How can I manipulate the results of the query, so that I have all the months. See example output:

[image]

*BTW: If you are asking why 2020-11 is showing up. This is due to the fact that in this month there was exactly the same amount of negative and positive, resulting in 0*.

Comment: Welcome. *"If you are asking why..."* Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to wrap your existing QUERY in an extended formula:

`=ArrayFormula({"Month", "Amount"; DATEVALUE("2020-"&SEQUENCE(12,1)),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(DATEVALUE("2020-"&SEQUENCE(12,1)),QUERY(A2:I;"select I, sum(C) * -1, count(C) group by I order by I ASC"; 1),2,FALSE),0)})`

You see that the headers here are generated in the opening of the formula.

`DATEVALUE("2020-"&SEQUENCE(12,1))` will create a sequence of dates covering 12 months (12 rows) in one (1) column.

`VLOOKUP` will lookup each element of the above `SEQUENC`E in your `QUERY`; and `IFERROR` will assign `0` for any months that are not found.